# Data visualisation using pymongo, mongodb, keen, crossfilter, d3 and dc

Tags: python, mongodb, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am trying to visualise in keen.io dashboard the numbers of entries in my mongodb collection. I have read few tutorials, which were far to complex for my level of html and javascript, but still I am not managing to render the html using keen, crossfilter, d3 and dc.

Btw if anyone can suggest an easier way to learn this please post it.

This is my code for the server side (app.py) and I am using flask for this

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json
from bson import json_util
from bson.json_util import dumps

app = Flask(__name__)

MONGODB_HOST = 'localhost'
MONGODB_PORT = 27017
DBS_NAME = 'mydb'
COLLECTION_NAME = 'mycollection'
FIELDS = {"Date": 1, "_id": 0}


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/mydb/mycollection")
def cocacola():
    c = MongoClient(MONGODB_HOST, MONGODB_PORT)
    db = c[DBS_NAME]
    projects = db.trades.find({}, FIELDS, limit=1)
    #projects = collection.find(projection=FIELDS)
    json_projects = []
    for project in projects:
        json_projects.append(project)
    json_projects = json.dumps(json_projects, default=json_util.default)
    c.close()
    return json_projects

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000,debug=True)
```

This is my html.index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dashboard</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/lib/css//bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/lib/css/keen-dashboards.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/lib/css/dc.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/css/custom.css">


</head>
<body class="application">

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="./">Dashboard</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row">

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">

  <!-- Metric 1 -->
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="chart-wrapper">
      <div class="chart-title">
        Total days
      </div>
      <div class="chart-stage">
        <div id="#total-days-nd"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Metric 1 -->


</div>

</div>

<hr>

</div>

<script src="./static/lib/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./static/lib/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="./static/lib/js/crossfilter.js"></script>
<script src="./static/lib/js/d3.js"></script>
<script src="./static/lib/js/dc.js"></script>
<script src="./static/lib/js/queue.js"></script>


<script src="./static/lib/js/keen.min.js"></script>
<script src='./static/js/graphs.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my graphs.js

```
queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "/mydb/mycollection")
    .await(makeGraphs);

function makeGraphs(error, projectsJson) {

    //Create a Crossfilter instance
    var ndx = crossfilter(projectsJson);

    //Calculate metrics
    var totalDays = ndx.groupAll().reduceSum(function(d) {return d["Date"];});

    //Charts
    var totalDaysND = dc.numberDisplay("#total-days-nd");

    totalTradesND
       .formatNumber(d3.format("d"))
       .valueAccessor(function(d){return d; })
       .group(totalDays)
       .formatNumber(d3.format(".3s"));
    dc.renderAll();

};
```

So, every time I open localhost:5000 the dashboard is loaded everything seems to be fine, however the total days in not shown.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You should check `error` to make sure there isn't one. Also probably `console.log(projectsJson)` (or set a breakpoint) to make sure the data is in the format you expect (presumably `[{Date: ...}, ...]`

Comment: Hi @Gordon. Thanks for the reply. How do I check error? :)

Comment: I mean something like `if(error) throw new Error(error)` at the beginning of `makeGraphs`

Answer (score 0):

```
var totalDaysND = dc.numberDisplay("#total-days-nd");

    totalTradesND
       .formatNumber(d3.format("d"))
       .valueAccessor(function(d){return d; })
       .group(totalDays)
       .formatNumber(d3.format(".3s"));
```

One line has `totalDaysND` and one has `totalTradesND`. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. No actually the problem was in the index.html file... #total-days-nd. There was an hash key that was not supposed to be there.